# Jasper report alignment not setting properly when printing more than one report

Tags: jasper-reports

[image: This is the 2 printed pages]

Here is my jrxml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.3.final using JasperReports Library version 5.1.0  -->
<!-- 2015-05-06T15:25:50 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="CWBI" pageWidth="720" pageHeight="380" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e84f85df-3881-49c6-9482-eed6dbfc3f01">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="OID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CNO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CUST_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PAYMENT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPPHONENO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPCNA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPADDR1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPADDR2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPADDR3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPADDR4" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPCOUNTRYID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPPOSTALCODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONCNA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONPHONENO" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONADDR1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONADDR2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONADDR3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONADDR4" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONCOUNTRYID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONPOSTALCODE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COPIES" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ATTN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONTENTS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="BFLYERS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SFLYERS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="RUSER" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="RDATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="RTIME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="REMARKS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PSTATUS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="380" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="32" y="27" width="79" height="18" uuid="48454381-ce78-46c8-a445-ffe05c226610">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CNO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="108" y="27" width="79" height="18" uuid="bc98f264-765e-4dd4-b32b-3571eb12e0cb">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CUST_NO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="185" y="27" width="59" height="18" uuid="f82b9de0-aaed-45aa-bc2a-e3d960f829b4">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SIN]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="174" y="67" width="131" height="18" uuid="e09f0461-c93c-4efb-a7a5-e1178b882fe5">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPPHONENO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="476" y="68" width="79" height="18" uuid="c1f28961-fe50-4c90-a9d7-9475edfa6fe9">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONPHONENO}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="88" width="262" height="18" uuid="cdb21b18-d208-421e-9841-776825e9b167">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONCNA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="572" y="14" width="68" height="64" uuid="f5bf25f8-2967-4e4e-bfa2-7879a3275e1c"/>
                <jr:QRCode xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA["Customer No: " + $F{CUST_NO}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:QRCode>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="88" width="260" height="18" uuid="74261339-33bd-4b4e-8868-424b374bcc50">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPCNA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="104" width="261" height="18" uuid="ace24046-246a-47ca-88ff-3e23e4a7d305">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPADDR1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="120" width="260" height="18" uuid="24669b62-c0e0-4d66-a7ea-1bf1fadf0b3a">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPADDR2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="135" width="260" height="18" uuid="4f1c4de3-1e04-4c1a-9037-28a0b5293f88">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPADDR3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="104" width="262" height="18" uuid="6a2a55cf-5dd0-416d-8a2d-c64d9b9090bf">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONADDR1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="121" width="262" height="18" uuid="bbc4faa6-a291-4852-8d01-4526fd664453">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONADDR2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="135" width="262" height="18" uuid="fd1b5507-5cb0-490c-8295-d6087fb12bb7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10" rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONADDR3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="61" y="164" width="104" height="18" uuid="317ce82b-3ba0-4204-a304-92b988c75391">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPCOUNTRYID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="213" y="164" width="67" height="18" uuid="46b78111-0e82-45a9-86ef-2ce120b87a1e">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPPOSTALCODE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="330" y="164" width="100" height="18" uuid="c9ca68be-593c-4bd5-9918-bf0fa51d25f1">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONCOUNTRYID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="497" y="158" width="58" height="18" uuid="950cf475-4a5a-4900-b33d-5de42950f9ed">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONPOSTALCODE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Here, I have attached my two invoices here. but If I set the printer paper for 1 print then it will be working properly , then If I put more than 1 print at the time then its printing like the above image, not set properly to the second page the QR code image is inside the first page and the ID line also not properly set like 1st page,

I need to print more than 1 print at the time and all the parameters should set the designed area. 
Can anyone suggest some tips for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is small or big the jasper report will support to all specified sizes So, you will remove the details band then try to putting your all inside the summary and try this it will help to you.

Also keep all the band as a blank or with small height.

Comment: I have tried like this but its also showing the same issue, but I remove the details band and keep the other bands as empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment on your question so I'll write an answer.
The xml you provide does not have the ID number in it, is this the complete xml? The barcode at the bottom is also missing.

Here is what I think is going on. It seems like your report is a little to small (the generated report is smaller than your paper). Can you provide us with the paper size?
Because the report is to small for your paper it causes the second report to be printed too early which explains the second report to start on the first page.

I do not have an explanation for your ID number since it is not in the XML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yeah this is my full xml, but I have purposely track the QR code in that place, because of the space, 
The paper size is 10×5 Inch, That's why I have put 720 × 360, then it will print like the above image so I try to change the height more than 360 but its also not working for me,

Comment: Not sure what is going on then but here is something I found out.
When I copy your xml in a jasper file the height of the report is 5,2778inch.  There is also a bottom margin of .2278.

try setting those to 5inch en 0inch.

Comment: Yeah, I am checking this report so it is not properly printing, thats why I am changing this.  but previously I put 5 inch. So, I didnot find the solution for this yet..

Comment: Try putting all your fields inside a frame and give that frame a border to see if the report get's pushed up/down or they just overlap...

Comment: frame also showing the same issue. Is there any paper alignment setting in the dot matrix printer?